# Jenkins and docker plugin: Problems to launch container

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, docker, containers

I have installed docker-plugin and configured it like in docker plugin instructions and used evarga/jenkins-slave image and custom images ( and tried with sshkeys and username&password credentials ) but i cannot run job. Connection test to docker cloud works but when i launch jenkins job it fails always like below.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/docker_test
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.builder.DockerBuilderControlOptionProvisionAndStart.execute(DockerBuilderControlOptionProvisionAndStart.java:32)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.builder.DockerBuilderControl.perform(DockerBuilderControl.java:59)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Build step 'Start/Stop Docker Containers' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have Docker version:

```
    Client version: 1.6.0
    Client API version: 1.18
    Go version (client): go1.4.2
    Git commit (client): 4749651
    OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
```

and  Docker plugin 0.9.0-rc1.

All hints and instructions how to get this work with evarga/jenkins-slave image are wellcome :)

Comment: it started to work after i added label and i have same image name in job and cloud settings. It should be possible to execute different images from the same cloud , right ?

Comment: Yes, You can setup different cloud to use different image.

Comment: I have the same problem. Some null exception after Jenkins pulls the image!